# Elliptic curves has multiplicative reduction

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

> Assume that $char(k) \neq 2,3$ Let $E/K$ be given by a minimal
>   Weierstrass equation of the form  $$E: y^2=x^3+Ax +B$$ Prove that $E$
>   has multiplicative reduction iff $4A^3+27B^2 \in \mathcal{M}$ and $AB \in R^*$.

By Proposition 5.1 in chapter VII Silverman's AEC book we see that $E$ has multiplicative reduction if and only if $v(\Delta)>0$ and $v(c_4)=0$, i.e., $\Delta \in \mathcal{M} \Leftrightarrow 4A^3+27B^2 \in \mathcal{M}$ and $c_4 \in R^* $.

How can I conclude that it is equivalent to $AB \in R^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $\Delta = -16(4A^3 + 27B^2)$ so if $4A^3 + 27B^2$ is in $\mathfrak m$ then $v(\Delta) \geq 1 > 0 $. We also know that $c_4 = -A/27$, so if $AB\in R^*$ then $A\in R^*$ hence $c_4 \in R^*$ and we are done by the proposition.

For the converse, we obviously have $\Delta \in \mathfrak m$ and $A \in R^*$ (examine the work above). But then we know
$$-16*27B^2 = \Delta + 16*4A^3$$
and so the LHS has valuation 0 (because the RHS does), hence $B$ has valuation 0 because $v(\Delta) > 0$ and $v(16*4A^3) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you @TokenToucan. Why does RHS have valuation 0?

Comment: It is the sum of something divisible by $p$ ($\Delta$) with something coprime to $p$ ($4A^3$).